# Angular showing HTML tags in browser instead of image

Tags: javascript, html, angular

First, sorry if it is very simple question, is my second month learning JS.

I upload an image  to my site [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwIAU.jpg) to show like an avatar image for user, but it only shows HTML tags not the image itself, actually HTML directs to correct link of image in my coputer folder but don't show any image, only the HTML tags..

This are the instructions to show the image:

```
<div class="image_for_edit" *ngIf="user.image && user.image != 'null'">
      <img src="{{url + "get-image-user/" + user.image}}" styles="width: 50px;">
</div>
```

Then instead  of the image, browser shows this:

```
 <img src="http://localhost:3977/api/get-image-user/Gja384icVy1nFy1tp6ZvVzEK.jpg"
 styles="width: 50px;">
```

Why is happening this? Don't give any error on mongodb or console, file uploads fine to the correct folder and seems everything fine, only have this problem. And I cannot find any error i've been searching on internet all day why can be this with Angular but still not find a solution.

Hope someone can help me a little to solve this..

Comment: you need to put out an empty picture tag and then fill it with the source, after you uploaded a picture.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: When you load the page for the first time, it will display an empty picture like this: <img src="" id="picture-to-fill"/>. When someone uploads a picture, you set the src of the img by the id.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-src` for image tags instead of `src`. Note also that you should use single quotes ' inside the double-quoted attribute value.

```
<div class="image_for_edit" *ngIf="user.image && user.image != 'null'">
    <img ng-src="{{url + 'get-image-user/' + user.image}}" styles="width: 50px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but not working, now shows <img ng-src="url + "get-image-user/" + user.image" styles="width: 50px;">

Comment: Check your quotes. Also I realized earlier I was incorrect about not needing the {{}} so I edited the answer.

Comment: It gives error in console: 

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-src' since it isn't a known property of 'img'. ("

Answer (score 0):

In Angular2:

```
  <img [src]="{{url + 'get-image-user/' + user.image}}" styles="width: 50px;" />
```

In Angular1:

```
  <img ng-src="{{url + 'get-image-user/' + user.image}}" styles="width: 50px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that.

in src tag, give your folder path.

```
<img src="api/get-image-user/{{ user.image }}" alt="" styles="width: 50px;"/>
```

Comment: It means file not found.

Comment: I think you need to correct you file path in src tag.

Comment: Working, thanks!! i use like this  <img src="http://localhost:3977/api/get-image-user/{{ user.image }}" alt="" styles="width: 50px;"/> which will need to change later on, but for testing now is fine, sorry still cannot vote